# Android Dagger2 ComponentProcessor was unable to process

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm trying to make multi module project with `Dagger2`. You can see my code [following the link](https://github.com/Ircover/SchulteTables). In the `main` branch is working solution where all the dagger classes are in `presentation` module.

Now I'm trying to make separate `app` module for the DI root. You can see the latest attempts [in the `develop` branch](https://github.com/Ircover/SchulteTables/tree/develop). It's not working. I want to make my root `ApplicationComponent` component in `app` module and add there `PresentationComponent` (sub)component from other module. Every time I try something, eventually I get following:

> dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process 'ru.ircover.schultetables.app.ApplicationComponent' because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code

It's very strange as I didn't change any dependencies in comparison with `main` branch. The only thing changed - new link from root component `ApplicationComponent` to child `PresentationComponent`. As I understand it, there is no way to appear circular dependency as `app` module and its content is not visible in `presentation` module. I've followed all the tutorials I've met in google, but none of them helped.

What I've already tried:

1. Add to root component getter of subcomponent.
2. Add to root component `Builder` or `Factory` of subcomponent.
3. Add to root component special module with `subcomponent` link.
4. Move `inject` methods of child component to the parent.

Now I'm stuck. It seems that the problem is somewhere in components or modules connection, but I can't manage to find where and how it happened. I need help here.

Comment: Typically the expectation on StackOverflow is to post a minimal reproducible example—all the code in the question, not a link to a repo—and a full error message. Can you reduce your example and still reproduce? Are you sure there are no additional error messages like your ComponentProcessor error message alludes to? Without those, this question will feel more like a guessing game than a solvable problem.

Comment: @JeffBowman I wish I had more error messages, but I haven't. All I found - the issue in the `dagger` repo, where they want to develop their error messages. But as I know it's still wasn't done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to build your project with these changes:

1. To the left is a presentation, to the right is an app, as you can see, I've removed dagger-android, AND make moxy deps as API (because your app is a main module, it has to see all deps to build a graph), or you can just add moxy deps to the app[image]
2. and after that, there won't be any dagger warning, but you need to fix some of your files to complete the build. Btw, to pass something to module's constructor is a bad and deprecated practice. As you can see in PresentationModule I removed constructor and removed provideContext. And I moved a Context binding to the ApplicationComponent - it is the good and right place to do it. [image]
3. And I also removed constructor parameter from PresentationComponent.Factory.create [image]

Comment: Man, you saved my pet project) Thanks a lot. Especially for best practice tips.

Comment: Can you additionaly share your way to debug it?

Comment: @Ircover what do you mean by "debug it"?

Comment: How did you conclude where to search for reason? I'd never think that problem is because I added moxy library in some incorrect way.

Comment: @Ircover In this specific case I knew it, because I had some similar problems in the past, and I tried to check it. And yeah, sometimes dagger warnings tell you nothing about the error, and only if you know what you are doing, you can find the error eventually.

Answer (score 11):

Based on [Google documentation](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.34) you can do this:

1. Add `@HiltViewModel` annotation to the class
2. Replace the `@ViewModelInject` annotation on the constructor with `@Inject`.
3. Remove `@Assisted` from the `SavedStateHandle` constructor parameter - if it exists
4. Remove the old `androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel` dependency from your `build.gradle` file

Comment: Thanks, removing number 4 did the trick for me.

Comment: 4th option worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the dagger.android support libraries, since your moxy.MvpAppCompatFragment is [built on Android Support Fragments](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/blob/master/moxy-app-compat/src/main/java/com/arellomobile/mvp/MvpAppCompatFragment.java). Add this to your presentation gradle file:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger_version"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"
```

---

From your develop branch's [presentation/build.gradle](https://github.com/Ircover/SchulteTables/blob/ee49ce38dd2ea819bf9753bb558c73e71e5abe47/presentation/build.gradle#L51-L53):

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"
```

From the [Gradle setup](https://github.com/google/dagger#gradle):

> If you're using classes in dagger.android you'll also want to include:
>
> ```
> implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.x'
> implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.x' // if you use the support libraries
> annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.x'
> ```

Comment: Added to both `app` and `presentation` gradle files - didn't help.